# What is the use of Tmp(email) in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

I'm using Db2, today I ran this query.

```
MERGE INTO table1 AS A 
    USING (VALUES('${user.email}')) AS TMP(EMAIL) 
        ON A.EMAIL=TMP.EMAIL
```

so, in this part the key word `AS`, does it create `TMP` as a new table or not?

I try some analogy in MySQL but it tell me wrong.

```
select *
from table1 join
     table2 using (id) as TMP(EMAIL);
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly you're trying to do. Please, provide a `table1` definition (DDL), sample data, and what data change your `MERGE` statement should do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AS TMP(EMAIL` is a *correlation clause*, which is a part of [*table reference*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html?pos=2)

It assigns an "alias" (correlation name) to the table generated by the `VALUES` statement, and also a name to its only column. MySQL v8 also [supports this syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) for tables that are subselects.

Your mistake in the second example is that you split the correlation clause away from its table name. It should look like this (note that you cannot assign column aliases here because `table2` is not a subselect):

```
select *
from table1 join
     table2 as TMP using (id);
```

In this example you *can* assign also a column alias:

```
select *
from table1 join
     (select 'foo@bar.com') as TMP (EMAIL) using (EMAIL);
```